# Exclude Table during pg_restore

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

**UPDATE:**
Was able to exclude the data in the table durning the pg_dump command. Makes it even faster than trying to not load the data because you don't have to wait for that data to be dumped.

`--exclude-table-data=event_logs`

`(PostgreSQL) 9.4.4`

Anyone know how to exclude a table when doing a `pg_restore`? I can find how to do it when doing a `pg_dump`. However I am not the one doing the dump and can't exclude them.

There are 2 tables in the dump that are really big and take forever when I do a restore so I want to skip them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[pg_restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-pgrestore.html) does not have an exclude table parameter, what it does have is an include table parameter.

> -t table
>
> --table=table
>
> Restore definition and/or data of named table only. Multiple tables may be specified with multiple -t switches. This can
> be combined with the -n option to specify a schema.

If you have a large number of tables it does call for a litte bit of typing, but it does allow you to exclude specific tables by just leaving their names out of the list.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah we have a lot of tables but I am making a rake task to automate this so I will just have to do it once. Could loop over the tables and have an exclude list of the 2 tables.

Comment: @covard would you be so kind as to share your rake task? it would be extremely useful.

Answer (score 77):

I had the same problem. A long table list, and I want exclude the data from a few of the tables.

What I did was the following:

Run

```
pg_restore -l $pgdump_file > restore.pgdump.list
```

Open that `restore.pgdump.list` file in an editor, and insert an `;` in front of the line saying

```
;2429; 0 27550 TABLE DATA public <table_to_explore> <database>
```

After saving the that file, it can now be used for importing, where all lines starting with `;` are ignored.

```
pg_restore -L restore.pgdump.list | psql
```

You could make an one-liner to add `;` in front of lines having a specific table name, if you completely want to ignore a specific table.

`man pg_restore` is also telling about this in an example in the end of the documentation.

Comment: Thank you, what a life saver! As noted in the `man pg_restore`, once you've edited the `restore.pgdump.list` file (from your example), you can call `pg_restore -L db.list db.dump` (in your example, you call `pg_restore` and pipe it to `psql` -- however, you do not specify the path to the dump file..?)

Comment: Note that this saved me because I was trying to exclude 2 tables from a list of 99 tables that were imported. `pg_restore` does not allow to specifying tables to exclude during import, so I had to call it: `pg_restore -t a_table -t another_table -t yet_another_table`, etc. Attempting to call it with 97 `-t` arguments broke with a "too many arguments" message... :-) Your `restore.pgdump.list` solution worked!!

Comment: This was very helpful!

I needed to only exclude data from a single table: `reports`.  I was able to do an inline `grep -v` when creating the list file.



```pg_restore -l $pgdump_file | grep -v "TABLE DATA public reports" > restore.pgdump.list```

Comment: Very nice now I want to tell my old coworkers to implement this to help save them time. This is awesome thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 28):

**TL;DR One-liner**

```
pg_restore -L <(pg_restore -l /path/to/db/dump | grep -v 'TABLE DATA public table_to_ignore ') -d db_name_where_to_restore /path/to/db/dump
```

---

The following returns the "todo list" for a restore:

```
pg_restore -l /path/to/db/dump
```

The following will return all except `table_to_ignore` (`grep` option `-v` makes it inverse the match):

```
pg_restore -l /path/to/db/dump | grep -v 'TABLE DATA public table_to_ignore '
```

This can be used in combination with `pg_restore` option `-L` which expects a input todo list:

```
pg_restore -L <(pg_restore -l /path/to/db/dump | grep -v 'TABLE DATA public table_to_ignore ') -d db_name_where_to_restore /path/to/db/dump
```

---

If you have several tables to ignore, you can the grep to:

```
pg_restore -l /path/to/db/dump | grep -vE 'TABLE DATA public (table_1 |table_2 |table_3 )'
```

Notice the presence of `-E` option for `grep` to use an extended regular expression.

Comment: you need to add a space after the table name like so `'TABLE DATA public (table_1|table_2|table_3) '` because otherwise `table_1` would also match `table_11` etc.

Answer (score 7):

here the command did not work:

```
pg_restore -L restore.pgdump.list | psql
```

answered by Jesper Grann Laursen!

Here it worked by following the following sequence:

```
pg_restore -l $pgdump_file > restore.pgdump.list

;2429; 0 27550 TABLE DATA public <table_to_explore> <database>

pg_restore -v -L restore.pgdump.list -d dbname pgdump.file
```